# Implementation of Socket IO

Tags: laravel, redis, socket.io, laravel-echo

I am implementing socket io in my project. I have installed redis, laravel-echo server and node. Now I am trying to call socket io in my project using `http://myserver:6001/socket.io/socket.io.js` but it is giving not found error.

I have tried many solutions but socket io is not working. Please help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure laravel-echo-server is running. If it is not then you can initialise it using `laravel-echo-server init` and then start it using `laravel-echo-server start`

Comment: laravel echo server is running. Infact I have setup supervisor to run in background and I can see log file and it is logging event and channel.

Comment: Did you cross check the ports?